# customize schedule primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I'm working on an application where I have to show a time table, where rooms shown at the left side, hours of the day on the top, and courses positioned accordingly (a typical time-table for schools).
Until now I'm using primefaces and jsf for view, but I couldn't find any resource on primefaces docs to help me construct the view.
what should I do ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are not talking about a `p:timeline`? https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/timeline/custom.xhtml

Comment: Yeah, that is what I'm looking for. Thank you.  clearly I didn't search enough.